# Foreign Key Constraint in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have two tables Cal and EEL
I want to use the primary key of cal that is Cal_id as the foreign key for EEl

Here's what I tried.

```
Create table ELL 
  (course_code varcahr2(10) Constraints pk_course_code Primary Key, 
    Course_Title varchar2(30),
    cal2_idnumber not null,
     Constraint fk_cal2 Foreign Key (cal_id) References cal_id(cal2_id)
)
```

but it shows error at line 6 Ora-00904 "Cal_ID" invalid character

can someone tell me how to do this

Comment: r u trying to create table EEI?

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
add CONSTRAINT constraint_name
  FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
  REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n);
```

Comment: You said the tables are named CAL and EEL.  EEL needs the foreign key constraint so that would be the table naem.

Answer (score 0):

Not difficult, here below an example:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier
(   supplier_id     numeric(10)     not null,
    supplier_name   varchar2(50)    not null,
    contact_name    varchar2(50),   
    CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id)
);


CREATE TABLE products
(   product_id  numeric(10)     not null,
    supplier_id     numeric(10)     not null,
    CONSTRAINT fk_supplier
    FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id)
    REFERENCES supplier(supplier_id)
);
```

Comment: what id did is this Create table ELL (course_code varcahr2(10) Constraints pk_course_code Primary Key, Course_Title varchar2(30),cal2_idnumber not null,Constraint fk_cal2 Foreign Key (cal_id) References cal_id(cal2_id) but it shows error at line 6        Ora-00904 "Cal_ID" invalid character

Answer (score 0):

`References cal_id(cal2_id)`   -- `call_id` is not your table name.

Instead of above code you can use as below.

```
References parent_table_name(cal2_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Constraint fk_cal_id2 Foreign Key (cal2_id) References cal(cal_id)
----------- constraint name       (col in EEL)    parent table name(parent table column name)