# Table using Foreign Key Oracle

Tags: oracle, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I am having a problem linking two tables in oracle 11g express addition.  I have looked on this site for assistance, but I am unable to find what I need.

My BOOKS table was loaded up using the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE STATES(
ST VARCHAR2(2) PRIMARY KEY,
STATES VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);
```

The CUSTOMERS table that I am trying to load is written as such:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
CUST_ID NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
STREET_ADDRESS_1 VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
STREET_ADDRESS_2 VARCHAR2(20),
CITY VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
ST VARCHAR2(2),
ZIP_CODE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
PHONE_NUMBER_1 VARCHAR2(20)NOT NULL,
PHONE_NUMBER_2 VARCHAR2(20),
EMAIL VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
CREDIT_LIMIT NUMBER(7,2) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY ST REFERENCES STATES(ST)
);
```

However, when I run the statement I get the following error:

```
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I believe that the error is in the FOREIGN KEY portion of the statement, as I can load the table without that statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreign Key Constraint in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604099/foreign-key-constraint-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error while declaring foreign key constraint
Correct one:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
CUST_ID NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
STREET_ADDRESS_1 VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
STREET_ADDRESS_2 VARCHAR2(20),
CITY VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
ST VARCHAR2(2),
ZIP_CODE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
PHONE_NUMBER_1 VARCHAR2(20)NOT NULL,
PHONE_NUMBER_2 VARCHAR2(20),
EMAIL VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
CREDIT_LIMIT NUMBER(7,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMERS FOREIGN KEY (ST) REFERENCES STATES(ST)
);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
CUST_ID NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
STREET_ADDRESS_1 VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
STREET_ADDRESS_2 VARCHAR2(20),
CITY VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
ST VARCHAR2(2),
ZIP_CODE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
PHONE_NUMBER_1 VARCHAR2(20)NOT NULL,
PHONE_NUMBER_2 VARCHAR2(20),
EMAIL VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
CREDIT_LIMIT NUMBER(7,2) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (ST) REFERENCES STATES(ST)
);
```

Comment: For some reason my version of Oracle 11g didn't like the constraint key word.  However, I was able to get my CUSTOMERS table and the rest of my database up and running with your assistance based on the bottom solution.  Thanks